# How to reset mat-button-toggle-group in angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How to reset `mat-button-toggle-group` after `onSubmit` click in angular?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking cuase: `mat-button-toggle-group` is available in angular 5 >

Comment: See mat-button-toggle-group----https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview

Comment: and how to reset mat-toggle-button

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]="selected"` for `<mat-button-toggle-group>` and when you want to reset it then just set the variable to *`undefined`*

HTML Code:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
<br>
<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

TS Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-toggle-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  selected : any =  'underline';

  reset(){
    this.selected = undefined;
  }
}
```

[`Working StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6abjsh)

Comment: Thank You Sir,you are given perfect answer.

Comment: For those who couldn't get this to work, the new way is set equal to `null` instead of undefined.

Comment: what if we have multiple select option ([(ngModel)] cant be used)?

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-button-toggle-group'. So?

Comment: @integrater can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: it a fair complex system , so i cant

Comment: same problem as @integrater